# Expert System engine

Tags: expert-system

Next year will be my graduate year to be an  informatics engineering person and I am trying to find ideas about the jounior project. Actually, I have an idea of making an expert system engine. I worked with clips and prolog and I liked clips very much but it seems to be an old engine. Can any one advice me about this idea or give me sources for papers or any topics that may help me? I am thinking to use C language to obtain the high performance, and to build a robust data structure. Also, I am thinking about an idea (I dont know if it could be done) of writing facts and rules (like clips) and then generate a C++ optimal code from these rules such that I can obtain the speed of the machine and use exe file.

I need help to make this idea more clear and how it can be done. Specially because I read about fuzzy logic, nueral network and heard about the new generation of expert system, so I dont know how that can be related to such topic.

Comment: How important is speed to your project? Is your project supposed to run in real-time, or does it just need to run in a reasonable amount of time on large datasets?

Answer (score 1):

For your junior project, I would recommend against writing it in C. Your problem sounds like it needs correctness more than it needs speed. Writing it in C will take longer because you will need to implement a lot of primitives that are not included in the language or any standard library. Also, since C is relatively low-level, there are a lot of opportunities to make low-level mistakes. Write it in a higher level language that is closer to the problem domain. You will have more time to focus on your actual problem because you will spend less time getting the framework set up. If you already know Prolog, it would be good to stick with that. Perhaps you might consider [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_programming_language). It is similar to Prolog, but also [designed for speed](http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/research/mercury/information/motivation.html).

Comment: Actually i am good C# programmer but i am against using it because of the intermediate language MSIL which makes performance decrease, and performance is one of the important ideas that make people use high level language such as C++ instead of clips.
Thanks..

Comment: @Hani - Clips uses a RETE network to solve the many-many pattern matching problem.  If you use C# or C++ (or any non-rule or non-logic language) you will have this problem.  The issue might not show up for few data elements and only a few hundred rules but computational complexity will bite you after a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Rules (also known as Drools) offers the best approach to rule-processing. It's written in Java. It allows you to integrate program components in the rules, and rule-bases into your program components. You can even build or modify rule-bases on the fly.

I've heard that Java is catching up in its ability to do math, but outside of that, you have nothing to fear from performance.